# An Exercise on Common Zero Locus and Vanishing Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals

Consider the subset $X:=\{(t^{2},t^{3})|t\in\mathbb{C}\}$  in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$, and set $X_{0}:=X\backslash\{(0,0)\}$. Show that $$\mathcal{V}(\mathcal{J}(X_{0}))=X.$$Note: here $\mathcal{V},\mathcal{J}$ stand for the common zero locus and vanishing ideal functions, respectively.

Could you please give me a hint as to what to do? This is my first time actually working with algebraic varieties, and I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Well, do you know what the definitions of those things are? (That is, can you write them down?) Also, you're missing some vital information - the vanishing ideal function depends on the ambient space. Where are you looking to calculate $I(X_0)$?

Comment: Yes, I have been looking at the definitions and very basic properties for a while now. As for the ambient space, I assumed it is $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, so that's where I'm looking to calculate $I(X_{0})$. I can see that $X$ is an (affine) algebraic variety, but I do not understand how to justify it. I assumed that I need to show that $X_{0}$ is not an algebraic variety, hence $V(I(X_{0}))=X$ because by definition it is the "smallest" variety containing $X_{0}$.